# Using Docker inside VirtualBox (preferably via Vagrant / Vagrantfile)

Tags: virtualbox, docker, virtual-machine, vagrant

How to make VM with Virtualbox (preferably with `Vagrantfile`), that allows running `Dockerfile` inside? (architecture: x86-64)

Objective: I would like to benefit from VirtualBox VM isolation (for safety), while run inside Docker (if not possible something that can run `Dockerfile`), as `Dockerfile` is very popular standard de facto. To make it "as a code" if possible, let's use `Vagrantfile` to define VirtualBox VM.

Non objective: using Vagrant with Docker as provider.

Hypothesis why it does not work:
IDK, but I guess that it may have something to do with nested virtualization?
As my objective is to utilize Virtualbox isolation of VM, then if needed, we can configure inside VM docker to be less "secure" if it will make it work, as we use VM for isolation here.

I tried different options, non works, so providing some files for easy copy&paste `vagrant up` start:

Alpine `Vagrantfile`: (does not work)

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "alpine/alpine64"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo apk update
    sudo apk add docker
    sudo rc-update add docker boot
    sudo service docker start
  SHELL
end
```

ArchLinux `Vagrantfile`: (does not work)

```ruby
$script = <<-'SCRIPT'
pacman --noconfirm -Syyu
pacman --noconfirm -S docker
gpasswd -a vagrant docker
systemctl docker enable
systemctl docker start
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "archlinux/archlinux"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "Archlinux_With_Docker"
    v.memory = 512
    v.cpus = 2
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```

Comment: Dear reader, if you came across similar issue as me, this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61277588/544721 . I try to figure out how does it work -> i.e. what's difference between "provisioner" vs "provider" and if it providers security isolation that I look for.

Comment: Difference between Vagrant provisioner vs provider : https://stackoverflow.com/q/38872670/544721

Comment: Notes: https://gist.github.com/gwpl/fb30eddbe0b0624186b96ebdfc457d69
Docker or Vagrant as a Desktop (or QubesOS) for isolating applications for better desktop security